# Bootstrap 3rd col breaks after 2nd row of 3/4 columns

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a bootstrap wordpress design, and I'm using some PHP to output the posts.

However, with any approach, whether it be col-3, col-4, col-2, I get a single portfolio item aligned right in it's own column, then the correct columns return.

Here is my code:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-lg-4 col-sm-4 pbox'); ?>>

    <?php
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 720, 560, true ); //resize & crop the image
    ?>

    <?php if($image) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <h2 class="box-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="box-meta"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>    
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
```

Here is a graphical example of my problem:
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMFQY.png

[image]
Additional CSS:

```
.pbox{margin-bottom: 30px;}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Posted an answer to your question. If you would like more detailed help, please post the generated HTML from your PHP code so that I can provide you with a working example.

Comment: Or you can copy/paste the generated html and CSS to the bootply http://www.bootply.com/ and figure out what is wrong. bootply is the best place to practice bootstrap related issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once had the same issue and it was because of each column having a varying height. I assigned a fixed column height and things started to look good. Here is my post which no one answered until i figured out myself https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/119009/responsive-bootstrap-grid-with-6-columns-of-equal-heights

See the following tests, I did just now (second row, third column is 200x190, everything else is 200x200)

[image] 
200x190 causes the last div to move to the right. but, if we assign a fixed height to each div, then things look normal as follow (the second row third div is still 200x190

and now the following

[image]

So I recommend that just for testing purpose, add height:200px; to your .pbox and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you Raf, adding height:560px to the .pbox class has fixed the issue, and just to clarify what @fizzix stated above, which would be the more appropriate solution?

Comment: Either can be, I have not tried his solution and don't know how it works. When it comes to my solution, if you are worried about fixed height across all devices, then you can resolve that by giving different fixed widths for different viewports i.e. for example, 560px for large screens, probably 360px for medium screen, etc. My solution has worked for me flawlessly. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid for Media Quries and don't forget to mark any solution that worked for you as ***Answer***

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if it is a problem with floats.

I recommend adding the following *before* the one that is breaking:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

That is a built in Boostrap class that clears all floats.

If you would only like it applied in certain widths, try the following:

```
<div class="clearfix hidden-xs"></div>
```

You can see the list of the responsive utilities [**here**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes).